# What is meant by "m|n"? Two letters separated by a vertical bar (|)

Tags: functions, relations

I am new to this subject, and not not sure what "|" symbol means on this statement.

Let $R_2 \subset\Bbb N \times\Bbb N$ be defined by $(m, n) \in R_2$ if and only if $m|n$.

Comment: $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane:  that is a full answer

Comment: Note that by the relation's definition, $\: 0 \hspace{.03 in} | \hspace{.03 in} 0 \:$ is true. $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$ m \mid n$ means that $m$ divides $n$.

We could also say that $n$ is divisible by $m$ AND we could also say that $n$ is a multiple of $m$,so $n=  a \cdot m, a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot..

Comment: I can't comment, so I put this as an answer, but this only adds to evinda answer. m divides n; or more precisely is that the rest of the division of N by M is zero.